# Microsoft Access 2007, about column value

Tags: ms-access

I'm pretty new to MS Access 2007, and I wanted to ask about something, that I couldn't find.

Is it possible that in a specific column, say for example: type, to make the only possible values "typea", "typeb"?

Just like the yes/no available option, just that it will contain my own specific values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can create a lookup table with the id and description (typea/typeb) values in and then reference this table. You can add a check constraint on the column to ensure the type entered matches the constraint specified. (typea or typeb).

Answer (score 1):

There is a way that involves only the basics.  Create a reference table for the valid values of Type.  It might have two columns, Id and Description.  The primary key is Id.
Put two rows in with Id values of "typea" and "typeb".  Put whatever you want for the description.  You might use this later.

Use the relationship tool to make the column in your existing table reference the Id column in the types table.  This will create a references constraint in the database.

Another response suggested adding a check constraint.  That will probably run faster, but may involve more learning on your part.

And, if you ever add a third and fourth type,  having a table like the one I've given will make it super easy to modify.